# Value of top cell and simple subtraction to the left being summed down

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to have two balances in the sheet, one for Cash and one for Bank.

This is what I have entered in google script and it works for the Cash `(=T3+R4-S4)` but for Bank it does this `=sum($X$3:X)-sum($Y$3:Y)`

I tried copying down what I had for Cash, but it will just copy the sum of the full row, rather giving me a balance after each transaction

This is on me appscript:

```
function onEdit(e){

  var CASH = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Master");
  CASH.getRange("T3").setFormula("=sum($R$3:R)-sum($S$3:S)");

  var lastrow =CASH.getLastRow();
  var fillDownRange = CASH.getRange(4,20, lastrow-2);
  CASH.getRange("T3").copyTo(fillDownRange)

  }

function onEdit(e){

  var BANK = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Master");
  BANK.getRange("Z3").setFormula("=sum($X$3:X)-sum($Y$3:Y)");

  var lastrow2 =BANK.getLastRow();
  var fillDownRange2 = BANK.getRange(4,26, lastrow2-2);
  BANK.getRange("Z3").copyTo(fillDownRange2)
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do - what are you trying to find the sum of specifically? The first thing I notice however that would cause issues is that you have two `onEdit` functions. Instead of this I would recommend having a single `onEdit` function that calls two different functions with the desired effect (or include both sets of code in the same `onEdit` function)

Comment: so I am calculating the balance as money comes in and out, the balance would be the previous cell (top one) added to money in (column R for example) subtracted by Column S for example, but how would it look like to have just one edit function (sorry I am super new to this)

Comment: To have them both in the same edit function you wouldn't have to change much - considering you have `CASH` and `BANK` both call the same sheet, you could just turn that variable into `SHEET`, and then since your other variable names are already differentiated, all you would have to do is change all the other places you refer to `CASH` and `BANK` into `SHEET` - and just have all of them in the same block of code.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve with your calculation. Can you provide a snippet of sample sheet with data in columns R,S, X, Y and the expected results in columns T and Z?